# Automating the download of a directory through FTP

Tags: xml, powershell, ftp

I need to automate the creation of a PDF in InDesign by watching for changes to an XML file, download all of the remote images referenced in the XML (because InDesign can't work with remote images), transform the XML to reference the downloaded local image paths, load up an InDesign template, then do an XML merge and export the results to PDF.

I am currently listening for changes to the XML file and launching InDesign using PowerShell, but I'm stuck on how to get the images I need.

I figured instead of trying to read the XML and pull down just the referenced images, I could just download the whole image directory. I've looked into doing this through PowerShell, using the *FtpWebRequest* class, but batch and .NET scripting isn't my strong suit, and I could only find examples of downloading individual files, or a list of files based on a CSV manifest.

I'm a JS developer, so I've looked into a Node.js implementation using a task runner like gulp and the ftp module, but I'm not sure if that's a good solution, or if it can even do what I want.

If you had to do this on a Windows machine, what would be your workflow?

Comment: Wouldn't it be sufficient to use `wget` or `curl`? Kinda the standard solution for such a task. And there's the built-in `ftp` utility that can be used to download all remote files.

Comment: I was able to serve the images via HTTP instead of using FTP, which made things a little easier. My solution was a complete node.js implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to use node.js and gulp to create a build environment that listens to a directory (using gulp-watch) and kicks off a build when an XML file change is detected:

```js
gulp.task('watchXml', function() {
    watch('input/*.xml', batch(function (events, done) {
        gulp.start('build', done);
    }));
});
```

I use the npm *request* module to download the images via HTTP (instead of FTP), and stream them to the local file system using the *fs* module. After the downloads and XSLT are complete, I can run a shell command to launch InDesign using `child_process`:

```js
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

gulp.task('shell', function(done) {
    exec('start "" "C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe InDesign CC 2015\\InDesign.exe"', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        if (err) {
            done();
            return console.log('error:', err);
        }
        console.log('InDesign launched.');
        done();
    });
});
```

From there, the InDesign startup script takes over, imports the XML, and creates the PDF.

Comment: Be aware that your solution may just violate the InDesign EULAs as the person (or worse system) depositing xmls hence running the the automation might not be the InDesign Client licence owner. In such 'server' environments, you need a InDesign Server licence. This systeme will be legal if you the licence owner deposit the xml file and run your system.

Comment: @Loic, I appreciate you bringing possible legal issues to my attention, but your examples aren't clear to me. I am generating the XML from a 3rd party system (SAP), and placing the file in a shared directory on a Windows VM where InDesign and the node.js application runs. Is that a violation of the EULA? Would you be able to provide the clause(s) in question so I can look at the language?

Comment: See points 2.1.7.1 et 2.1.7.2 in the /Legal/en_GB/license.html : http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/818141Capturedecran20160916a111053.png

Comment: Thanks, @Loic. I think I'm in the clear, because the software is not installed on a server.